# Setting path of fs.appendFileSync?

Tags: node.js, fs

How do you set the path of fs.appendFileSync? For example, I want to make a file in folder "X" but my code is in the folder above. How would I create the file in another folder than the one my code is in(the file is made in the same folder as the source code).

I've read the documentation but I don't understand how I would be able to specify where to create the file.

Comment: Did you look at how the `path` module works, specifically, `path.resolve()`?

Comment: No, can you link the documentation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The variable `__dirname` represents the directory that the currently running script is located in.  So, if you wanted to put a file in a sub-directory below that (let's say it is in a variable called `someDir`), then you would do that like this:

```
const path = require('path');

let pathToFile = path.join(__dirname, someDir, "filename.txt");

fs.appendFileSync(pathToFile, dataToWrite);
```

If that directory doesn't yet exist and you need to create it, then you could use `fs.mkDirSync()` to create i.

```
const path = require('path');

// make sure sub-directory is created
let dirForFile = path.join(__dirname, someDir);
if (!fs.existsSync(dirForFile) {
    fs.mkDirSync(dirForFile);
}
// append data to the file
let pathToFile = path.join(dirForFile, "filename.txt");
fs.appendFileSync(pathToFile, dataToWrite);
```

Comment: @moltasdev - Does this answer your question?